# Given a set of possible starting nodes, find the smallest path that visits certain nodes and returns back

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I have a set of nodes (<= 10,000) and edges (<= 50,000) which connect all of them with some combination. That is, you can visit any node starting from any other using atleast one combination of edges. The edges have their length defined.

I am supplied a set of mustpass nodes (maximum 5). All of them have to be visited, and we can pass through them multiple times if needed. We need to start our journey from one of the nodes which are not mustpass, visit all mustpass nodes, and return back to our initial node.

We need to find the shortest distance of such a path.

Say we have 5 nodes indexed `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` and the following edges in the format `node -> node : length` (all undirected):

```
1 -> 2 : 1
1 -> 5 : 2
3 -> 2 : 3
3 -> 4 : 5
4 -> 2 : 7
4 -> 5 : 10
```

And the mustpass nodes are `1, 2, 3`. Our shortest distance can be achieved when we start from node 5, have a path as such: `5-1-2-3-2-1-5`, and hence travel a distance of `12`. `12` is our desired output.

Is there an efficient way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here`s O(E log V) solution:

1. Lets consider starting node as must-pass node
2. Using Dijkstra find shortest paths between all pairs of "must-pass" nodes
3. Now problem is reduced to Traveling Salesman Problem with 6 cities
4. We can either check all permutations in O(6!) time or use dynamic programming for O(2^6 * 6^2) either way since 6 is a constant complexity is O(1) for this part

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't get it clearly, but here's what I understood: We take an arbitrary point from the possible starting points (here, 4 and 5). Say we take 4, include it in our list of must-pass, and find the path of shortest complete cycle, like in the TSP. We store this distance. Then, operate similarly taking 5 as our starting point, and compare this distance to the previous distance to find the smallest. 

We can have almost 10,000 starting points, so do we do the same process for all of them to find the best solution? That is, to find the best starting point?

Comment: @ShivenSinha Running Dijkstra at each of the must-pass nodes will give you shortest paths from each must-pass node to every other node. The final step is to loop over all of the non-must-pass nodes and determine which order of must-pass nodes is best for this initial/final non-must-pass node.